# Referência com um triângulo amarelo, o que significa?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

Quando possui uma exclamação, entendo que a referência está com problemas e precisa ser removida/reinstalada. Mas com esse pequeno triângulo, não sei. Vi que o pacote está instalado. Nesse caso, o que eu devo fazer? Veja o screenshot das referência do meu projeto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou re-instalar?

Comment: Então, só queria saber o que significa o triângulo, se é algo novo ou se alteraram a imagem de referências com problemas, entende. É só para saber mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Depende. Se abrir a sua janela de `Lista de Erros` deverá ter um warning que explica porque essas referencias estao a Amarelo. Mas pode dever-se a uma das seguintes razoes:

- O pacote pode ter problemas de compatibilidade com a plataforma da aplicacao (Por exemplo, este warnings sao comuns se voce refere pacotes da framework 4.6.* em .net core)
- O pacote nao é compativel (ou pode ter problemas de compatibilidade) com a versao da .net framework que voce está usar. Exemplo voce estava a usar um pacote da versao 4.6.* e mudou a versao do seu projeto para 4.5
- O pacote está corretamente referenciado mas o MSBuild nao conseguiu encontra-lo no sitio indicado (remover a referencia e instalar novamente o pacote pode ajudar)

Comment: Bruno, obrigado pela explicação. Se for apenas um warning, menos mal. É que não consigo desinstalar o pacote. Tentei remover a referência e referenciá-la novamente e nada. Apenas uma está assim com problemas e não consigo atualizar, somente a `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` está assim. As demais foram corrigidos. Existe uma forma manual de desinstalar o pacote? Sei que o post não foi esse, mas tem a ver, já que a referencia está bugada.

Comment: A referência é o seguine. Aponto para a referência na pasta: `C:\Mobile\Autorizador\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.42.1021.1\lib\MonoAndroid70` e adiciono. Quando abro as referências, ela tá com essa imagem e na propriedade **Caminho** está em branco, ou seja, não está apontando para lugar algum. Como ela vem num pacote, creio que copiar e jogar em outra pasta, pode dar problemas maiores, certo?

Comment: @pnet Tem sim o comando `Uninstall-Package <nome do pactore>` deverá funcionar. Também deve puder alterar o ficheiro `*.csproj` manualmente. para remover a referencia manualmente. Em relacao a localizacao do pacote nao me lembro muito bem, fiz um projeto em Xamarim á uns 3 anos atras e lembro-me também de ter tido uns problemas em relacao a isso...